# Allow Remote Access Users to remote VPN site trought HQ Office GW Check Point Appliance

Tags: vpn

I have a Check Point 1430 Security Appliance. This device has an IPSec Tunnel to remote network (Azure). I want to permit access to remote access users (Client To Site VPN) for this remote site. I've searched for hours, but I can't find any solution to solve my problem. I can ping Azure servers from HQ Office LAN but I'm not able to ping from remote access computer at the moment.

[image: Topology]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention a Check Point management server so I suppose you are managing the Check Point gateway locally.

The requested functionality you are describing is sometimes called "VPN routing". For the Check Point embedded appliances (600/700/1100/1400/1200R) and VPN clients it is described in the SecureKnowledge article [sk109094](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk109094): How to reach an internal network behind a Site-To-Site VPN tunnel, when connected with Remote Access to locally managed Check Point 600/700/1100/1400/1200R appliances.

Here are the important steps. In the article you can find also the screenshots:

1. Go to "VPN" tab -> Advanced Settings. Check the "Office Mode Network" setting. This network address should overlap neither with the Azure networks nor with the HQ networks.

> Explanation: The Office Mode network defines which IP addresses will be assigned to the VPN clients.

2. In the VPN tunnel definition on Cisco add the Office mode network to the addresses located behind the Check Point gateway.
3. In the Advanced Settings of the Remote Access VPN, check the "Route Internet traffic from the connected clients through this gateway" checkbox.

---

To troubleshoot the setup check in the corresponding logs that the communication from the VPN clients to the Azure addresses is being sent to the site2site VPN by the Check Point gateway - and vice versa - communication from Azure to the Office Mode addressees is  being sent to the site2site VPN by the Cisco gateway.